# Detect Session Ended By User in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using .NET 6

How can I detect session ended by user? I found many solutions which developers have implemented in different ways, but why does this event not exist in .Net 6?

I created a middleware to check online users. Within, I have two `DateTime` properties to store `StartSession` and `LastRequest` and for each request that my application receives, all items in `Dictionary` will be checked, the difference time between the two properties compared, and then exceeding 30 minutes (Expire time of cookies in `appsettings.json`) results in registering as an offline user, proceeding in necessary action.

So why does ASP.NET Core 6 not support session events?

Thank you all

Comment: But, in this solution I don't know how can I SignOut user from his sessionId. Online user data is stored in IMemoryCache.

Comment: IsAvailable property from ISession interface might help

Comment: This property works on available session which is belong to current user, but how can I manage other user's session as admin of application?